# How to use array value in filtering for ArangoDB?

Tags: arangodb

stack overflow community i am relatively new for arango and wants to build an AQL query using two collection please help me

first collection :- user
JSON :-
"user_id": "abcd",
"program_info": [
{
"program_id": 101,
}
]

Second collection :- program
JSON :-
{
"program_id":101,
"program_name": "test"
}

---

i am building query to get info of program name using both collection if user_id will supplied
FOR u IN user FILTER u.user_id =="abcd"
FOR p IN program
FILTER p.program_id == u.program_info[*].program_id
RETURN p.program_name

but i am getting blank [] array please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `u.program_info[*].program_id` returns an array with all `program_id` attributes from the objects in the `program_info` array. However, you are comparing this array with the scalar value `p.program_id` which does match and therefore you get an empty array. I suppose you want to check if `p.program_id` is *contained* in user's `program_info`. That could be done like this:

```
FOR u IN user
  FILTER u.user_id =="abcd"
  FOR p IN program
    FILTER p.program_id IN u.program_info[*].program_id
    RETURN p.program_name
```

However, for better index usability it might even be better to rewrite your query like this (provided you have an index on `program_id` for the `program` collection):

```
FOR u IN user
  FILTER u.user_id =="abcd"
  FOR pid IN u.program_info[*].program_id
    FOR p in program
      FILTER p.program_id == pid
      RETURN p.program_name
```